# Searching for Ruby GUI toolkit, GUI applications

Tags: ruby, user-interface, desktop

Which GUI toolkit do you think is the most powerful and widely used among ruby programmers? Are there any popular desktop GUI applications built in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot comment on "most widely used", Qt4-Ruby is quite powerful:
[Qt4 Ruby Tutorial](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Qt4_Ruby_Tutorial).
I have used it and like it. On MacOS there is [Ruby Cocoa](http://www.rubyinside.com/the-ultimate-list-of-rubycocoa-tutorials-tips-and-tools-728.html), which seems to be quite popular.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on OSX [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/) is the thing you want to check out!
MacRuby in combination with [HotCocoa](http://www.macruby.org/hotcocoa.html) has excellent support for building cocoa applications, it even works with Interface Builder (an IBOutlet for example is just a matter of declaring attribute accessors in your ruby classes) and is under very active development.

Other than that, I wouldn't necessarily recommend ruby as the first choice for building GUI applications. I'm not saying that it is impossible, but it's just not Rubys primary domain and therefore the community and tool support is far from being optimal. Then again, MacRuby is great and fun to use!

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/). It's crossplatform.